# Error The type or namespace name 'Networking' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' in UWP target, how to fix project.json in multi-target project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, project.json

I can't figure out how to make UWP target build in my project (class library) which defines "netstandard1.3" and "uap10.0" targets.

I was successfully able to build UWP project if I create it as a separate project of UWP type in Visual Studio 2015 wizard but I'd prefer to build it as one of targets in a single multi-target project (where I'd add more targets then).

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.0.0",
        "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1",
        "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.1",
        "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.0.0",
        "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0",
        "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.11",
        "System.Net.Security": "4.0.0",
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs": "4.0.0",
        "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.0.0",
        "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0",
        "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1",
        "System.Globalization.Extensions": "4.0.1"
      }
    },
    "uap10.0": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "",
        "System.Runtime.Extensions": "",
        "System.Windows": ""
      },
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
          "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
          "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.0.0",
          "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1",
          "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.1",
          "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.0.0",
          "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0",
          "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.11",
          "System.Net.Security": "4.0.0",
          "System.Reflection": "4.1.0",
          "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.1.0",
          "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0",
          "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0",
          "System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs": "4.0.0",
          "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.0.0",
          "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0",
          "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1",
          "System.Globalization.Extensions": "4.0.1"
        },
        "buildOptions": { "define": [ "WINDOWS_UWP" ] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find any simple example how to write project.json for UWP libraries (ideally, multi-target project for UWP and non-UWP at once). So I'm mainly using trial and error (by adding this or that sections and moving them around project.json) but with no success.

For example, it seems frameworkAssemblies System.Runtime, System.Runtime.Extensions, System.Windows are not valid for UWP but I can't guess which ones should be there. If this section is not there, it doesn't get build either. I've honestly spent days on reading project.json specs and all the differences between its directives but it's still blurry.

netstandard1.3 target builds without problems. Actually, I was happy with building UWP as a separate project but this didn't scale when I then wanted to add win8-wpa81 (I'm striving to support as many platforms for my library as possible) and that's why I decided to migrate to a single project with multi-target project.json

Answer (score 0):

Not all .NET APIs were supported in UWP. You could refer to [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185501.aspx)

I didn't know what your project's type is. But if you want to compatible with windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 app. I think you could think about create a "windows 8 - Universal - Windows Runtime Component(Portable for Universal Windows8.1)". You could add reference to it in UWP project and win8-wp81

[image]

Comment: My selection for UWP was Class Library(Portable for iOS, etc). Your link doesn't mention Windows.Networking. Again, I have no problems when building UWP project as a separate project. You're describing how to create a UWP project. I've already done that and it's working. I'm wondering if it's possible to 'merge' UWP target into a .NET Core class library which would have UWP target in addition to netstandard1.3 target. Is it possible to have a single project which can build many diff. versions of class library, including.NET Core, UWP, Win8, etc?

Comment: @Alex I think it's impossible.